arm aarch64 keyboard setting up for qemu emulator
Wanna add keyboard input for qemu emulator. I have C file for UART logic:
void uart_puts(const char *str);
void uart_putc(char c);

void notmain(void) {
    volatile char *uart = (char *)0x1c090000;  // UART базова адреса
    char c;

    uart_puts("UART test...\n");

    while (1) {
        c = *uart;  // Читаємо символ з UART
        if (c != 0) {  // Перевіряємо, чи є дані
            uart_putc(c);  // Виводимо символ на екран
        }
    }
}

void uart_puts(const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        uart_putc(*str++);
    }
}

void uart_putc(char c) {
    volatile char *uart = (char *)0x1c090000;
    *uart = c;  // Виведення символа в UART
}

And here .s file:
    .globl _start
_start:
    mov sp, #0x20000          // Встановлюємо стековий вказівник
    bl notmain                // Викликаємо C-функцію notmain
hang:
    b hang                    // Безкінечний цикл

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str w1, [x0]              // Записуємо значення з регістра w1 в адресу, на яку вказує x0
    ret                       // Повертаємося з функції

So, in C code i wrote logic for visualisation symbols when i press btns from keyboard. I use aarch64-linux-gnu for compiling all files. Here command for compilling asm file:
 aarch64-linux-gnu-as --warn --fatal-warnings -march=armv8-a strap.s -o strap.o
Here for compilling C file:
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -march=armv8-a notmain.c -o notmain.o
I also link all files using linker which code is that:
/*memmap*/
MEMORY
{
    ram :ORIGIN = 0x10000, LENGTH = 32K
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*)} > ram
    .bss  : { *(.bss*)} > ram
}

And command for linking:
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld strap.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
and for using objects i use objcopy command:
aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary os.bin
When i visualise i did not see any symbols in console when i pressing buttons:

I use this command for visualisation:
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a53 -m 128 -serial mon:stdio -kernel os.bin
I use WSL ubuntu system
So what i need to fix:

visualise bin file in qemu gui virt (without parametr -noghraphic)
keyboard 'answering' in emulator


A little detail which is not relevant to question, your RAM base address should be 0x4000_0000 on QEMU's virt board and most likely differ on different boards

Guest code can rely on and hard-code the following addresses:


Flash memory starts at address 0x0000_0000


RAM starts at 0x4000_0000



Quoted from https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/arm/virt.html#hardware-configuration-information-for-bare-metal-programming

volatile char *uart: Is the uart register really a byte?  Hardware registers are usually words.

1st section "visualise bin file in qemu gui virt (without parametr -noghraphic)"
Could you update the question to clarify what you mean visualizing "bin" file which is just list of instructions and data and doesn't have any structure, please?
2nd section "keyboard 'answering' in emulator"
I assumed by 'answering' you meant echo'ing back the key you inputted.
UART base address is most likely wrong
I can't be certain if your situation special (and QEMU indeed place UART device base address there for some reason) due terminal being partially obscured (QEMU -serial mon:stdio flag redirects serial output to terminal) so I can't see whether UART test... being printed or not (Please update the screenshot so it fully includes terminal too)
Assuming that 0x1c090000 indeed the wrong base address, the correct UART base address should be  0x9000000 for your emulated board (QEMU's virt board and I dumped device tree blob and search for the address on my QEMU 9.0.2)
